# Howto detect current page in ScrollView.pagingEnables = YES?

Tags: objective-c

is there anything more comfortable than this to detect a "special" page? The page should be fully visible.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{

    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width * 2) {
        NSLog(@"Special page");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Normal page");
    }

}
```

Comment: in iphone scrollView.contentOffset.x / 320  gives (int + 1) is your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://github.com/shoktong29/MultiPageScrollView) a sample project I recently created regarding this.

Hope this helps. :)